# Laravel 5.6 Route

Tags: laravel-5.6

```
This is the mean problem
I have controllers structures like this
```

[image: File Structures]

```
And i am using this syntax to make routes which is worked good for me
```

[image: web/routes]

```
And i calling url in this way
```

> {{ route('admin.categories.show', [$category->id]) }}

```
i got this error
```

[image: Error]

```
Any Solution ?? thanks in advance guys
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When grouping routes, it is possible to namespace them by adding flag `as`:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function (){
    Route::resource('categories', 'Admin/CategoryController');
});
```

Now `route('admin.categories.show')` should be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is

> {{ route('categories.show', [$category->id]) }}

skip the admin thanks every one .